# Question about sigma algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

The experiment is as follows: A die is rolled and the coin is tossed and the outcome of the experiment is noted then what will be the suitable sigma algebra for this experiment?
My try is we have sample space here let say $\Omega$={(1,H),(2,H),(3,H),(4,H),(5,H),(6,H),(1,T),(2,T),(3,T),(4,T),(5,T),(6,T)} ,let the set of sigma albera is $A$={$\Omega$,$\phi$},my question is what ate the other elements in $A$ ,like if I put an element $(1,H)$ then what will be it's complement?

Comment: The set of other elements left in $\Omega$.

Comment: Since $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\times\{H,T\}$ is a finite set, you can use the largest possible sigma-algebra, the power set $\mathcal P(\Omega) := \{S : S\subseteq\Omega\}$, i. e. the set of all possible subsets of $\Omega$. Since $\{(1,H)\}\subseteq\Omega$, we have that $\{(1,H)\}\in\mathcal P(\Omega)$. However, if you choose $A$ as sigma-algebra, then $\{(1,H)\}\not\in A$. In either case $\{(1,H)\}^\complement = \{(2,T), (3,T), (4,T), (5,T), (6,T)\} = \{1\}^\complement\times \{H\}^\complement$.

Comment: Since $\Omega$ has $12$ elements, the power set (all subsets of $\Omega$) has $2^{12} = 4096$ elements. I like to call the elements of the sigma-algebra "events".  Note $(1,H)$ is not an event, but $\{(1,H)\}$ is an event with one element.  Its complement then has the remaining $11$ outcomes.